# Passing Data between BottomNavigation fragments via NavigationComponent

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation, bottomnavigationview

Is it possible to pass Parcelable object/arguments between BottomNavigation controlled Fragments via NavigationContoller?

Here is the flow of my app, user logs in to app and a fragment is opened which contains BottomNavigation. I was able to get the argument to first fragment(first fragment opens using         `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(action)` ) i was able to add arguments to this action and pass values, but BottomNavigation doesn't have any navigate instructions navigation is done via menuID. How can i pass logged in user argument between all these bottom navigated fragments via bundle.

I tried to pass arguments using onDestinationChanged()

```
@Override
public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
        NavArgument argument = new NavArgument.Builder().setDefaultValue(selectedUser).build();
        destination.addArgument("user", argument);
}
```

but still app crashes with     `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required argument "user" is missing and does not have an android:defaultValue`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can either user SharedViewModel as asad has mentioned or we can use NavGraph to set argument

```
navController.getGraph().findNode(R.id.todoFragment)
            .addArgument("user", new NavArgument.Builder()
                    .setDefaultValue(user)
                    .build());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.navBottomNavigation);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(R.id.bottomNavigationView, navController);
    NavGraph navGraph = navController.getNavInflater().inflate(R.navigation.nav_sub_graph);

    NavArgument argument = new NavArgument.Builder().setDefaultValue(yourObject).build();
    navGraph.addArgument("yourObject",argument);

    navController.setGraph(navGraph);
}
```

Passing Object nested Fragments in BottomNavigation

```
 navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {

            switch (destination.getId()) {
                case R.id.profileFragment:
                    NavArgument argumentProfile = new NavArgument.Builder().setDefaultValue(yourObject).build();
                    destination.addArgument("yourObject",argumentProfile);

                case R.id.homeFragment:
                    NavArgument argumentHome = new NavArgument.Builder().setDefaultValue(yourObject).build();
                    destination.addArgument("yourObject",argumentHome);

                case R.id.orderFragment:
                    NavArgument argumentOrder = new NavArgument.Builder().setDefaultValue(yourObject).build();
                    destination.addArgument("yourObject",argumentOrder);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SharedViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) also in navigation docs [Pass data between destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data) they refer

> In general, you should strongly prefer passing only the minimal amount
>   of data between destinations. For example, you should pass a key to
>   retrieve an object rather than passing the object itself, as the total
>   space for all saved states is limited on Android. If you need to pass
>   large amounts of data, consider using a ViewModel as described in
>   Share data between fragments.

Comment: thanks asad, user argument is just a integer value is SharedViewModel is the only option to share this userID between all BottomNavigated fragments?

Comment: you can only pass data to the start destination as per docs [Pass data to the start destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#start) and if you go with `onDestinationChanged` you cannot get arguments for the first time